# Having datadog listen to a socket in C++

Tags: c++, unix-socket, datadog

I have a the following function to publish datadog metrics

```
int PublishMetric(Metric* metric)
{
    printf("Sending metric to datadog metric: %s value: %.2f\n", metric->metricName, metric->value);
    DogFood::Tags datadogTags;
    for (int idx=0; idx<metric->numOfTags; idx++)
    {
        datadogTags[metric->tags[idx].tagName] = metric->tags[idx].tagValue;
    }
    DogFood::Metric(
            metric->metricName,
            metric->value,
            (DogFood::Type)metric->metricType,
            1,
            datadogTags
    );
}
```

I am now trying to change it so it will go through a socket, as I find in this following page:

https://github.com/garrettsickles/DogFood  under **UDS - Unix Domain Sockets (Custom)**.

Now the function looks like this:

```
int PublishMetric(Metric* metric)
{
    printf("Sending metric to datadog metric: %s value: %.2f\n", metric->metricName, metric->value);
    DogFood::Tags datadogTags;
    for (int idx=0; idx<metric->numOfTags; idx++)
    {
        datadogTags[metric->tags[idx].tagName] = metric->tags[idx].tagValue;
    }
    DogFood::Send(
        DogFood::Metric(
                metric->metricName,
                metric->value,
                (DogFood::Type)metric->metricType,
                1,
                datadogTags
        ),
        DogFood::UDS("/var/run/datadog/dsd.socket")
    );
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get 'not a member' errors. How can I include them as members?

```
/TCP_Server/src/DatadogAdapter/DatadogAdapter.cpp: In function 'int PublishMetric(Metric*)':
/TCP_Server/src/DatadogAdapter/DatadogAdapter.cpp:30:14: error: 'Send' is not a member of 'DogFood'
     DogFood::Send(
              ^~~~
/TCP_Server/src/DatadogAdapter/DatadogAdapter.cpp:30:14: note: suggested alternative: 'Set'
     DogFood::Send(
              ^~~~
              Set
/TCP_Server/src/DatadogAdapter/DatadogAdapter.cpp:38:18: error: 'UDS' is not a member of 'DogFood'
         DogFood::UDS("/var/run/datadog/dsd.socket")
                  ^~~
make[2]: *** [src/DatadogAdapter/CMakeFiles/DatadogAdapter.dir/DatadogAdapter.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Obvious question first: are you sure your copy of `DogFood.h` actually _has_ this function?

Comment: and have you included `DogFood.hpp`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles the function was already there, I just tried to wrap it. and yes it is included.

Comment: Did not reproduce, both simple example and your modifications compile for me. I only removed `Metric` argument because I don't have datadog.